# Deploy Vuejs App on Google App Engine get 404 error

Tags: vue.js, google-app-engine, deployment

I'm deploying a Vuejs application on App Engine, after deployed when I visit the application link I get 404 error:

[image: The error page]

in the log I see this error:

> Static file referenced by handler not found: dist/index.html

The file structure on App Engine is:

- App Engine

  - dist

    - index.html
  - app.yaml

[image: App Engine file structure]

My App.yaml file:

```
runtime: nodejs12

instance_class: F2

handlers:
# Serve all static files with urls ending with a file extension
- url: /(.*\..+)$ 
  static_files: dist/\1
  upload: dist/(.*\..+)$
  # catch all handler to index.html
- url: /.*
  static_files: dist/index.html
  upload: dist/index.html
```

I tried to upload a test folder and create an index.html file inside it and change the handler URL to point to the test folder, it worked, but with the dist folder it doesn't work.
Any help with this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try changing your `App.yaml` to

```
runtime: nodejs12

instance_class: F2

handlers:
# Serve all static files with urls ending with a file extension
- url: /(.*\..+)$ 
  static_files: dist/\1
  upload: dist/(.*\..+)$
  # catch all handler to index.html
```

The RE which you are using for URL should cover all the directories. If you want to query for only particular extensions, you can check the [following documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/appref#handlers_element).

Comment: It didn't work, I guess somehow the AppEngine can't see the dist folder while it exists!

Comment: @Mhm0ud I have updated my answer. Can you please check? I guess the issue can be due to using RE 2 times for URL. If it doesn't work, please let me know. I will try to help you with a different solution.